# Merging multiple tpk files to one tpk file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, tiles, vtpk

Is there a way, to merge the tpk files of different locations in single tpk file, such that the final result will have all the merged tpk files. I am looking for something as shown in the below image.

[image]